# How to automatically apply alternate Master pages in inDesign CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I have set up two different spreads as Master pages and I have to alternate between them as I add new pages I want the spreads to alternate A-B-A-B, cycling through about 200 pages.

Is there a quicker way to do this, than manually dragging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside of scripting, there isn't an automated way to do this as you work (automatically alternate spreads). You can, however, make it go a lot faster than drag and drop.

In the Pages Panel flyout menu there is an option `Duplicate Spreads`. Your first step is to assign a keyboard shortcut to that command.

- `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts...`.
- Select "Panel Menus" in the `Product Area:` dropdown, and navigate to `Pages: Duplicate Spread`.
- Choose a keyboard shortcut and type it into the shortcut field.
- Save. You'll create a custom shortcut set, since you can't alter the default set. Call it "Aasim's Custom" or whatever you like.

[image]

Now you get to the semi-automated part:

- Create two consecutive spreads using your A and B masters.
- Shift-click on their thumbnails in the pages panel so both are selected.
- Press your keyboard shortcut for "Duplicate Spread" as many times as you need.

Comment: If you need a very large number of pages, you can re-select all of your spreads again after each duplication - this will grow your page count exponentially.